# Trying to search for a string with (.*?) in Python

Tags: python, regex, findall

I am 3 days new to Python and I am trying to use findall() to search for a string character after a specified format

```
    >>> nameRegex = re.compile(r'First Name: (.*?) Last Name: (.*?)')
    >>> nameRegex.findall('This is my application for the job. First Name: 
       John Last Name: Johnson DOB 01/01/90')
    >>> [('John', '')]
```

I realize I am using the non greedy ? in the group because otherwise it would return the DOB portion of the string as well.

Is there a way I could format to take the Johnson string portion and nothing more?

Since I am so new I am not sure which direction to move to get the desired portion of the string.

Thanks to anyone in advance.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Why `$`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Then it will capture the DOB portion as well, as the OP has said...

Comment: I assumed with `portion` the whole after it using the dot star. If only the name, that that will over match it of course. If will remove the comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Anchor your regex pattern with a space in the end. That should help you to capture everything after `Last Name:` upto the next space

```
>>> nameRegex = re.compile(r'First Name: (.*?) Last Name: (.*?) ')
>>> nameRegex.findall('This is my application for the job. First Name: John Last Name: Johnson DOB 01/01/90')
[('John', 'Johnson')]
```

Comment: Awesome, that works perfect. How exactly does that blank space anchor work?

Comment: `.*?` is non-greedy and can match empty string`''`. But by anchoring it with a space, you say that there has to be a space after your match. So the minimal match that can satisfy this criteria is to match everything up to the next space

Comment: ahh that makes sense. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been answered for single-word last and first names, but they won't work if things get weird. Here's how you can handle all varieties of names (except for first names containing `" Last Name:"` and last names containing `" DOB"`):

```
nameRegex = re.compile(r'First Name: (.*?) Last Name: (.*?(?= DOB ))')
nameRegex.findall("This is my application for the job. First Name: Mary Beth Last Name: von Sternberg-O'Leary DOB 01/01/90")
```

This gives the correct output:

```
[('Mary Beth', "von Sternberg-O'Leary")]
```

The funny looking bit in the regex, `(.*?(?= DOB ))` , is a called a "positive lookahead". Put simply, this makes the group match the same strings as `(.*? DOB )` but discards `" DOB "` from the capture group.

[Here is an intro to lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which are be incredibly useful once you get familiar with them.

Comment: The idea is good, but it's better to use a non-greedy quantifier for the last name to be sure to stop at the first "DOB" in the line, and add a space after "DOB" (for John DOBSON). You can also do that `((?:(?! DOB ).)+)` (one by one but greedily).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Ooo, good catch! Also, that's an interesting alternative. I always forget about non-capturing groups.

Answer (score 1):

Change your regular expression to

```
nameRegex = re.compile(r'First Name: (\w*) Last Name: (\w*)')
```

This makes it match all Unicode word characters with `\w`, which does not include whitespace. Alternatively, you could use `\S` instead of `\w` to match all non-whitespace characters. For a reference on these special escape sequences, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

The output is then

```
[('John', 'Johnson')]
```

Comment: I had not thought of just using the \w* since I was just looking for a word, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to just use non-whitespace construct to get the names

`First\s+Name\s*:\s*(\S*)\s+Last\s+Name\s*:\s*(\S*)`

https://regex101.com/r/u1LPRD/1